# Can I overwrite the string form of a namedtuple?

Tags: python

For example:

```
>>> Spoken = namedtuple("Spoken", ["loudness", "pitch"])
>>> s = Spoken(loudness=90, pitch='high')
>>> str(s)
"Spoken(loudness=90, pitch='high')"
```

What I want is:

```
>>> str(s)
90
```

That is I want the string representation to display the loudness attribute.
Is this possible ?

Comment: Maybe you should create a proper reusable class instead.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes, it is not hard to do and there is an example for it in the [namedtuple docs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

The technique is to make a subclass that adds its own str method:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> class Spoken(namedtuple("Spoken", ["loudness", "pitch"])):
        __slots__ = ()
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.loudness)

>>> s = Spoken(loudness=90, pitch='high')
>>> str(s)
'90'
```

**Update:**

You can also used *[typing.NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)* to get the same effect.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Spoken(NamedTuple):
    
    loudness: int
    pitch: str
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.loudness)
```

Comment: What's `__slots__` usage here? Is it required or optional?

Comment: Setting ``__slots__`` to an empty tuple is a memory saving technique.  It makes sure that instances of ``Spoken`` take the same amount of memory as a regular tuple.  Without the slots entry, every instance requires its own dictionary (which is much bigger than a tuple).

Comment: Besides the memory savings, it's worth noting that Python versions up to 3.5.0 [define](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.0/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L324) a `__dict__` property. Thus, the decision on whether to set `__slots__`, which controls the definition of the `__dict__` attribute, affects the behavior of functions that interact with that `__dict__` attribute; e.g. if `__slots__` isn't set, `vars(s)` returns `{}` rather than `OrderedDict([('loudness', 90), ('pitch', 'high')])`. This was changed in Python 3.5.1, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34166469/3903832).

Answer (score 20):

You can define a function for it:

```
def print_loudness(self):
    return str(self.loudness)
```

and assign it to `__str__`:

```
Spoken.__str__ = print_loudness
```

Comment: out of curiosity, will this return an `integer` or a `string`, since your overloaded `str` is returning an `int`?

Comment: @Serdalis: Well spotted, this will incorrectly return an `integer`. Fixing it now.

Comment: I like this way, as it adds little text to the default way of using ``namedtuple``. You could even shorten it using a lambda expression without losing much readability (IMHO): ``Spoken.__str__ = lambda x: str(x.loudness)``. (Of course you can use [``%`` or ``str.format(...)``](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452) inside the lambda expression).

Answer (score 4):

you can use code like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class SpokenTuple( namedtuple("Spoken", ["loudness", "pitch"]) ):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.loudness)

s = SpokenTuple(loudness=90, pitch='high')

print(str(s))
```

This will wrap namedtuple in a class of your choice which you then overload the str function too.