# Did something about `namedtuple` change in 3.5.1?

Tags: python, typeerror, python-3.5, namedtuple

On Python 3.5.0:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> cluster = namedtuple('Cluster', ['a', 'b'])
>>> c = cluster(a=4, b=9)
>>> c
Cluster(a=4, b=9)
>>> vars(c)
OrderedDict([('a', 4), ('b', 9)])
```

On Python 3.5.1:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> cluster = namedtuple('Cluster', ['a', 'b'])
>>> c = cluster(a=4, b=9)
>>> c
Cluster(a=4, b=9)
>>> vars(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

Seems like something about `namedtuple` changed (or maybe it was something about `vars()`?).

Was this intentional? Are we not supposed to use this pattern for converting named tuples into dictionaries anymore?

Comment: @user2357112 - Yeah, I think this kind of change should be called out in the changelog. That's what made me think at first that it might've been a mistake.

Comment: "Are we not supposed to use this pattern for converting named tuples into dictionaries anymore" I suppose we never *were* supposed to use this pattern, as `vars(x)` is documented to return `x.__dict__`, but I don't think it was ever documented that `namedtuple` instances have a `__dict__` attribute. Such a pattern *is* documented for the `Namespace` instances in the `argparse` module, I know, so perhaps that's where the tendency arises. In any case, I'm sure there are going to be some surprised developers whose code breaks, so this is a great question.

Comment: PS: perhaps the title of the post should be amended to include `vars`? This might make it easier for the influx of searches to find this post once people start upgrading to 3.5.1 en masse.

Comment: @jme - Yeah, looks like `._asdict()` is the correct way to do this. Regarding search, I think the mention of `vars()` in the question body and answers will be enough to help people find this question.

Comment: Fair enough. Also, I stand corrected that the use of `vars()` was never documented: in the [Python 3.3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict) it states that `the same effect can be achieved by using the built-in vars() function` when referring to the functionality of `_asdict()`.

Comment: @NickChammas I don't think calling a method whose name begins with `_` from outside the class is ever the correct way to do something…

Comment: @BlacklightShining That is indeed a convention in python, but this is an exception to the rule.  The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict) mentioned "to prevent conflicts with field names, the method and attribute names start with an underscore."

Comment: Unfortunately, Python doesn't seem to have an explicit policy forbidding backwards-incompatible changes in micro versions. Micro versions [are supposed to just be "bugfixes"](https://docs.python.org/devguide/devcycle.html),  but without a policy forbidding it things like this happen repeatedly.

Comment: @JeremyBanks arguably they *did* fix a bug. The bug allowed the first example to work, but breaks it in the second instance. Of course as jme mentioned, that bug was actually documented as a feature...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Per [Python bug #24931](http://bugs.python.org/issue24931):

> [`__dict__`] disappeared because it was fundamentally broken in Python 3, so it had to be removed.  Providing `__dict__` broke subclassing and produced odd behaviors.

[Revision that made the change](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/fa3ac31cfa44)

Specifically, subclasses without `__slots__` defined would behave weirdly:

```
>>> Cluster = namedtuple('Cluster', 'x y')
>>> class Cluster2(Cluster):
    pass
>>> vars(Cluster(1,2))
OrderedDict([('x', 1), ('y', 2)])
>>> vars(Cluster2(1,2))
{}
```

Use `._asdict()`.

Answer (score 12):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields)

> Named tuple instances do not have per-instance dictionaries, so they are lightweight and require no more memory than regular tuples.

The  [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict) (and `help(namedtuple)`) say to use `c._asdict()` to convert to a dict.

Comment: the interesting thing is that `vars` worked on python3.5.0 . . .

Comment: The removal of the instance dict might have happened in 3.5.1

Comment: Fair enough, that does seem to be the officially sanctioned way to do it. Shame is that much of the advice on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26180528/877069) recommending `vars()` is now incorrect. I wonder if this was intentional on the developers' part or just an accident.

Comment: `vars()` only works if the object has a `__dict__` attribute. If namedtuples had this dict they would require more memory than regular tuples. This was determined to be undesirable. Therefore the `__dict__` was removed, and thus `vars()` doesn't work. It is intended.

Comment: @ChadS. the `__dict__` attribute was already just a property, `namedtuple`s have `__slots__`.

Answer (score 9):

`__dict__` was implemented as a `@property` and has been removed; you can see the change in the source code:

[3.5.0](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.5/file/tip/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l323):

```
def __repr__(self):
    'Return a nicely formatted representation string'
    return self.__class__.__name__ + '({repr_fmt})' % self

@property
def __dict__(self):
    'A new OrderedDict mapping field names to their values'
    return OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self))

def _asdict(self):
    'Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values.'
    return self.__dict__

def __getnewargs__(self):
    'Return self as a plain tuple.  Used by copy and pickle.'
    return tuple(self)

def __getstate__(self):
    'Exclude the OrderedDict from pickling'
    return None
```

[3.5.1](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.5.1/file/tip/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l323):

```
def __repr__(self):
    'Return a nicely formatted representation string'
    return self.__class__.__name__ + '({repr_fmt})' % self

def _asdict(self):
    'Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values.'
    return OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self))

def __getnewargs__(self):
    'Return self as a plain tuple.  Used by copy and pickle.'
    return tuple(self)
```