# Pythonic way to convert NamedTuple to dict to use for dictionary unpacking (**kwargs)

Tags: python, dictionary, namedtuple, iterable-unpacking

I have a `typing.NamedTuple` that I would like to convert to a `dict` so that I can pass into a function via dictionary unpacking:

```py
def kwarg_func(**kwargs) -> None:
    print(kwargs)

# This doesn't actually work, I am looking for something like this
kwarg_func(**dict(my_named_tuple))
```

What is the most Pythonic way to accomplish this?  I am using Python 3.8+.

---

**More Details**

Here is an example `NamedTuple` to work with:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class Foo(NamedTuple):
    f: float
    b: bool = True

foo = Foo(1.0)
```

Trying `kwarg_func(**dict(foo))` raises a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

Per [this post on `collections.namedtuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166604/11163122), `_asdict()` works:

```py
kwarg_func(**foo._asdict())
{'f': 1.0, 'b': True}
```

However, since `_asdict` is private, I am wondering, is there a better way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `._asdict`.

`._asdict` is **not private**. It is a public, documented portion of the API. [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

> In addition to the methods inherited from tuples, named tuples support
> three additional methods and two attributes. To prevent conflicts with
> field names, the method and attribute names start with an underscore.